# How to center image to the left of my header?

Tags: html, css

I am making an HTML website for a school project and I want to center an image to the left of the header. By header, I mean the big thing that says World vector control. I put the image to float left but it just stays put in the top left corner for some reason.

```css
body {
  background-color: #252525;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: ultra;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: ultra;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #2E86C1;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #2E86C1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.navbar input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.navbar .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: ;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .search-container button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar a,
  .navbar input[type=text],
  .navbar .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .navbar input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}

.header {
  background-color: #252525;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  margin 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #2E86C1;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: ultra;
}

img {
  float: left;
}

#rcorners1 {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #fffafa;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  height: ;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="Untitled-2.png" alt="M" width="80" height="80">
  <h1>World Vector Control</h1>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">About</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
                    Introduction
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">The Problem</a>
      <a href="#">The Solution</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">
                    Contact Us
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Donate</a>
      <a href="#">Get Invovled</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="search-container">

    <form action="/action_page.php">

      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search">

      <button type="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>

    </form>

  </div>
</div>

<p id="rcorners1">Rounded corners!</p>
```

Comment: There's an extra brace in the css on `.navbar input[type=text]`; and a missing colon on the `header` class.

Comment: Do you mean vertically center?

Comment: yes I want it to be vertically centered beside the header text.

Comment: Cool. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I put the image on float left but that didn't work also I tried the image align attribute

Comment: Take a look at the margins on the H1. They're not in the css, they're just built-in for H1s. Add some css, adjusting the top and bottom margins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<img src="Untitled-2.png" alt="M" width="80" height="80" style="left:30px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that there's some margins and padding on the `div.header` and on the `<h1>`, an easy solution would be to make the `<img>` a child of the `<h1>`, then it'll be aligned exactly as the `<h1>`.

Removed unnecessary code for the sake of this explanation.

```css
* {
    
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.header {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    margin 0; }

h1 {
    border:1px solid black;
    color: #2E86C1;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: ultra;
    position: relative;
}

h1>img {
border:1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    height:100%;
    width:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <h1><img >World Vector Control</h1>
</div>
```